# eclipse IDE run error read /.metadata/.log

Tags: eclipse, exception, ide, workspace

Pre: Ubuntu, installed Eclipse in this way:

```
tar -zxvf eclipse.XX.YY.tar.gz
mv eclipse.XX.YY ~/opt
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse
Type=Application
Exec=/home/user/opt/eclipse/eclipse  #watch the directory!
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/usr/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE
Name[en]=eclipse.desktop

cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

after that (I had a workspace before) running eclipse throws an error to read workspace/.metadata/.log
Some people suggest to Delete: /YOUR PATH TO WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources
like here
http://bugsanddebugs.blogspot.com/2010/06/when-eclipse-says-error-has-occurred.html
but running 
eclipse -clean
gives the same error.
This almost exhaustive article helped a little... 
http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t99010.html
but still can't understand errors:

```
~/workspace$ egrep -A 2 "Caused by" ~/workspace/.metadata/.log 
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.console.command.adapter.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.console.
   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
--
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Activator.start() of bundle org.apache.felix.gogo.command.
   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
--
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.felix.gogo.command.OBR
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.12)
   at org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Activator.start(Activator.java:54)
--
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.Repository
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
--
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.Repository
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
```

how to read all this?

Comment: Migrated to full-loaded gedit (thanks to fascinating plugins list!). But from now using SublimeText2. Almost the same functionality can be reached in gedit with some restrictions, but prefer sublime because of coworkers programming flow consistency. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy JRE folder to the Eclipse folder. It may fix the problem. It works for me anyway.
The reason why the Eclipse won't start is that it started with an old version of the JVM.
See this reference for more details: **[eclipse won't start](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/405887/)** .

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the configuration/org.eclipse.osgi folder.